# Correctly display the colors in MATLAB colormap and colorbar?

Tags: matlab, colormap

I am plotting spatial maps with fill values ranging from `0.05` to `-0.05`

Below is the part of code for plotting colormap and colorbar

```
    colormap(brewermap([10],'RdYlBu'));       
    caxis([-0.05 0.05])
```

and here is the figure [image]

Here the problem is, each map has majority of the `0` fill values, but the color map show them in between `0 to 0.01` as depicted through colorbar.

Is it possible to assign some other color to `0` values?

Comment: Just manually adjust the map according to the API (https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) for whatever you think your fill value ("0") is (e.g. range -0.00001 to 0.00001). This isn't really a GIS question - more a generic matlab API question.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Its a matlab matrix. Just set the required values, per the API.